# Selenium: How to assert that a text field is disabled?

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit, selenium-rc

I am using the PHPUnit Selenium Extension for Selenium RC.

I am able to assert the field is present:

```
$this->assertElementPresent('Date');
```

But how do I assert that the field is disabled (or not editable)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isEditable()` will return true/false

```
$this->assertEquals(false, $this->isEditable('Date'));
```

...or better yet:

```
$this->assertNotEditable('Date');
```

Comment: You're answering a few of your own questions pretty quickly, perhaps spend a few more minutes trying to work it out before posting a question? :P

Comment: funny thing is I search all over to try to find the answer, can't find it, then post to stackoverflow. Once I figure it out, I will post my solution, but there may be a better one. Plus...if it's already hard to find the answer, better to post on stackoverflow to help others find the information easier/faster since they have good SEO. Just sayin' =]

Comment: if you install selenium IDE and then have a look at the commands that are there with what they do. You can then convert it to PHP in the idea to see what the equivalent is.